# Replacing instanceof for Java Beans

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, instanceof

I have encountered some code in a project at work where we have JavaBeans. I have discovered a `Writer` object that writes these beans to file. Unfortunately this uses `instanceof` to ask what type the bean is, before writing to file, like so:

```
if (bean instanceof BeanA) {
    writer.handleBeanA(bean);
} else if (bean instanceof BeanB) {
    writer.handleBeanB(bean);
} else if (bean instanceof BeanC) {
    writer.handleBeanC(bean);
}
```

This is ugly and I want to replace it. So I took a look at splitting my writer into new classes `Writer`, `BeanAWriter`, `BeanBWriter`, `BeanCWriter`. I did this because obviously to keep my JavaBean structure I cannot add a method `write()` to the Beans.

When I call `Writer`, I pass my bean in as an abstract parent `Bean`, because the function calling this writer doesn't care what type of bean it is dealing with.

Now I go to write my new classes I encounter a problem, the function that I am overriding looks like this:

```
public abstract boolean <T extends Bean> writeBean(T bean);
```

but the code in `BeanAWriter` looks like this:

```
public abstract boolean <T extends Bean> writeBean(T bean) {
    bean.accessBeanAProperty();
}
```

This code cannot work, because T is only recognised as a `Bean` and not as a `BeanA`, meaning that my `instanceof` is just replaced with a cast to `BeanA`...

Can anyone find a solution to this / what is going wrong here?

(I do not want to throw out the JavaBeans or hear about how it is an anti-pattern, as changing the beans could regress a lot of code).

Comment: how do you write them in the file? is that text file? json or something?

Comment: The writer will take specific (different depending on the type) fields from the bean and construct a byte representation from it, which is then saved as a text file.

Comment: Why does the writer need to downcast like this? It needs to access subclass fields?

Comment: ah you don't need all fields then. because beans by definition are serializeable so you can serialize them without carrying about the type. but it will store all fields

Comment: It's not serializing the fields. They are manipulated before they are saved in the file.

Comment: Make an `IBean` interface, and modify your various `Bean` classes to implement it. Then modify your method to take the interface (instead of a generic) and program to the interface.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have already tried that, but then I cannot access my `BeanA` specific fields.

Comment: @Radiodef Certain fields need are unique to each child bean, `BeanC` and `BeanA` have distinct fields.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to overload your method to take `BeanA` - `BeanC` and let the type system call the correct one.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that does not work as java does not allow multiple dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with class-based generics rather than method-based:

```
public abstract class BeanWriter<T extends Bean> {
    public abstract boolean writeBean(T bean);
}

public class BeanAWriter extends BeanWriter<BeanA> {
    public boolean writeBean(BeanA bean) {
        bean.accessBeanAProperty();
    }
}
```

Comment: But suppose they are given e.g. a `List<Bean>`. Now they are creating a writer for every bean and they still need to use `instanceof` to find out which writer to instantiate.

Comment: For making this work with `List<Bean>`, you'd have to have some kind of registry to map `Class<? extends Bean>` to `BeanWriter` instances.

Comment: @Rossiar This has all the same problems as `instanceof`. Now you need to make a writer for every Bean. If you map classes to writers then you're doing the exact same thing.

Comment: Well yeah, ideally I'd declare an interface `write()` and implement on a `Bean` by `Bean` basis. Or did you have something else in mind? Ideal is far from what I am allowed to deal with...